# different text positions in chrome. IE and FF

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am making a website with css and jquery. One of my script is to show a text at a specific location on a mouse click. The text is displayed good in google chrome at its intended position. but in IE9 and FF17 they are displaced from the intended position. My background image is such that it fits to the size of the window of the browser.

I am attaching the screenshot which will give a better idea. Also I am writing the code. maybe only a small tweak is required but I do not get it. Please help me  in this.

[image: This is the comparison between chrome and IE. the right one is chrome which is the right one. FF and IE display at same positions.]
This is the comparison between chrome and IE. the right one is chrome which is the right one. FF and IE display at same positions.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
*Here will my script which is just simple .show and .hide functions*
});
</script>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Train of Thought</title>

<style type="text/css">
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

body {
overflow: hidden;
}

#background {width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute; z-index:1;}

.content {
visibility:hidden;
border-style: none;
display: block;
position: fixed;
text-align: centre;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: 40%;
background-color: transparent;
font-size:1.5em;
opacity: 0.697;
}

#thought_text{
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
}


<div><img id="background" alt="background" src="tot1.png"></div>

<div class="content" id="thought_text">Here goes the text<br></div>
```

Comment: Have you added the reset.css to your stylesheet and the vendor prefix? This seems to be a compatibilty issue!

Comment: position:relative missing . add position relative..

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple hack that will work in IE9 for vertically centering elements. It uses the `transform: translateY` property to adjust an element within another element. We can apply a class to our inner element like so:

```
.element {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

You'll need to add the appropriate vendor prefixes. Here is a great article on this: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, for fixed positioning, use: `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` attributes instead of `margin-top`, `margin-right`..

Secondly, you've applied same `z-index`'es on siblings.

Thirdly, use of `img` element for background this way is not the best solution. 
You should go for CSS `background-image` for `body` or text-div wrapper, stretched to 100%.

Full solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// Here will my script which is just simple .show and .hide functions*
});
</script>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Train of Thought</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/6d28260f10f17c0d2eab47398fd855f6/tumblr_mj9ha54DuW1rub5xuo1_1280.jpg);
background-position: top center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.content {  
top: 40%;
display: block;
position: fixed;
text-align: centre;
z-index: 1;
background-color: transparent;
font-size:1.5em;
opacity: 0.697;
border-style: none;
}

#thought_text{
left: 25%;
right: 25%;
color:#000;
}

</style>

<body>

<div class="content" id="thought_text">Here goes the text<br></div>

</body>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing `#thought_text{}` block in css file and combining it in the `.content {}` block to avoid overriding of attribute values

**or**

adding !important directive to the attributes

**and also change**

`margin-top: 40%;` to some fixed value such as `margin-top: 250px;` which ensures the top positions as same in all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you stretch image to whole page and want to center your block with text. You have 50% width (100% - 25% margins from both side) and 40% top margin.

With `position:fixed` you have top and left properties to set position relative to page.

```
.content {
  position:fixed; /* taking it over the page */
  z-index:2; /* and over the image */
  left:25%; /* move to 25% from left */
  width:50%; /* and setting width */
  top:40%; /* move to 40% from top */

  font-size:1.5em;
  opacity: 0.697;
}
```

And you can remove

```
#thought_text{
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

You get original bug because top/bottom margin and padding in percents calculates from *width* not height according to [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties).

Answer (score 0):

this is just an idea , hope that useful .

```
<style>
    #background {
        background:url('tot1.png') no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
        position: absolute; 
        z-index:1;
    }
</style>
<div id="background">
    <div class="content" id="thought_text">Here goes the text<br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a bit of javascript to detect if IE or Firefox are present, and then change the margin/position of the text accordingly.

```
    function detectBroser(){
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1)
            return "Firefox";
        else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1)
            return "Internet Explorer";
    }
```

Comment: still browser sniffing is bad.

Comment: Mark - yes, but there's NO OTHER WAY I can think of.